# How to replicate the pronouns (pronominal) with their antecedents

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Given the following Text:

"Patient:   Fine, and the movie was fascinating. It was called First Angels, and it was about Lincoln -- it was based on a book, I guess. But it was about Lincoln when he was eight years old. The whole movie  w -- took place then. And in that span of time -- I mean he must have been like eight or nine, his mother died of some disease, and, um, he had a cousin, and the cousin's parents died. So the cousin was living with him. And the cousin's voice i -- the cousin tells the story. You very seldom hear Lincoln speak. And, um, you learn about the relationship with his father, and -- and his father leaves them to find a wife, and comes back with a wife and several children."

I need to replicate the mentions of "his,her,my,their...." with their actual antecedents. When I used Stanford coref. resolution, it gives me lots of mentions which are not useful like "his father" to "his father" or even "his father" to "his". I need the text have "Lincoln's father" or "Lincoln's mother".  I have list of mentions : 
[619, 625]=[647, 653], [565, 575]=[588, 598], [565, 575]=[588, 591].....
I can solve this problem in an ugly way of programming but I wonder if there is any method or way to clean extra mentions or a method helping for putting actual names in place of their pronouns?

Answer (score 4):

There is, to my knowledge, no clean way built into CoreNLP to replace a pronoun with its canonical mention. This is at least in part by design: this sort of replacement yields a bunch of nasty nuances in the general case: e.g., should the "original text" annotation change? Should the character offsets change? Can you recover the original sentence?

When we've had a need for this, we've attached an additional annotation (called, e.g., `AntecedentAnnotation`) to the tokens of a mention in a coreference chain, pointing to the canonical mention. You can get the canonical mention using the [`getRepresentativeMention()`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/dcoref/CorefChain.java#L109) function.

Comment: Yeah I've got a solution for offset changes. You can do a descending sort based on mentions offsets and make changes from tail towards the head of the text. In this way, any changes won't affect on the previous offsets. I use representative mentions method but it still gives me some mess...

Comment: @Christopher Manning  I hope that you have an answer for this question....your response would be the most appreciated

Comment: What is the question? Are you proposing we write a function to do this in CoreNLP, or are you asking if the method in your comment is valid?

Comment: @ Gabor Angeli  Yeah, I wonder if the suggested method, in my comment, is reasonable?

Comment: The method seems reasonable. The character offsets will not be representative of the actual character offsets in the original text, and you should be careful to clone the CoreLabels in question, but it sounds like it should work. Really, I recommend doing this after all the annotators have been run, or else you run the risk of strange things happening.